# Show a textblock if an ObservableCollection is Empty

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to show a textblock that says "you have no data" when a collection that should be shown is empty.

I can easily get this to work on page load by using a converter, but since that doesn't get notified when the collection data changes the code doesn't work:-

```
TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Devices, Converter={StaticResource EmtpyListToVisibility}, Mode=OneWay}" Text="You have no devices added, please press the Add Device button on the application bar" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>

<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,12,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices, Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeviceTemplate}" LayoutMode="List" VerticalAlignment="Top" >                       
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

In windows 8 apps I have added a property called xxxHasRecords, then I subscribe to the Observable collections CollectionChanged event and used the property notification so my UI can be updated. I find myself writing this code so often that there just has to be a better way of handling it!

Thanks

Ross

Comment: Using Converter can slow down your app, why don't you place both TextBlock and ListBox in the same Grid.Row, the toggle Visibilty of them when ObservableCollection is empty or not

Comment: How would I know if the observable collection was empty? I probably should have mentioned that I'm using MVVM - pretty key piece of info I suspect :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than bind to the `ObservableCollection`, you should bind to the `ObservableCollection.Count` property. The collection implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so will notify your bindings whenever its size changes. Your value converter then simply has to check for zero.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

```cs
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool invert = false;

        if (parameter != null)
        {
            invert = System.Convert.ToBoolean(parameter);
        }

        bool isVisible = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

        if (invert)
        {
            isVisible = !isVisible;
        }

        return isVisible ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility result = (Visibility)Enum.Parse(typeof(Visibility), value.ToString(), true);

        return result == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
    }
}
```

And change the binding of the `Visibility` property of the TextBox to the following:

```xml
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Devices.Count, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
    Text="You have no devices added, please press the Add Device button on the application bar"
    TextWrapping="Wrap">
</TextBlock>
```

When the collection is empty `Count` returns the value 0. The Converter uses `System.Convert.ToBoolean` which converts 0 to `false` and all other values to `true`.

False is returned as `Visibility.Collapsed` and true as `Visibility.Visible`.